# Read PDF File in Assets folder through PdfRenderer without creating tempfile

Tags: android, android-assets, androidpdfviewer, android-pdf-api

I have a pdf file in Assets folder and would like to open it up. I need to create a `File` as below in order to set as a `ParcelFileDescriptor` to pass to the `PdfRenderer`.

```
    private val pdfRenderer by lazy {
        val file = File(cacheDir, "tempFile")
        file.outputStream().use { fileOut -> 
            assets.open("TestPdf.pdf").copyTo(fileOut)
        }
        val fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
        PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor)
    }
```

This seems lame, as I need to create the temp file, even though I have the physical file in my Assets Folder. Is there a way to skip creating the temp file in cache?

Extra info: I tried using the below

```
    private val pdfRenderer by lazy {
        PdfRenderer(assets.openFd("TestPdf.pdf").parcelFileDescriptor)
    }
```

But I got this error `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed`.

I put this in build.gradle

```
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "pdf"
    }
```

And got this error `Caused by: java.io.IOException: file not in PDF format or corrupted`

Comment: Can not the pdf renderer read from an inputstream?

Comment: @blackapps, I am looking for that too. That works for me as well if you have a solution. Do PdfRenderer seems to take in File only. :(